# Page constructor called multiple times - Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a page in a WP8 application, that every time I navigate to it, the constructor is called.

From what I know, the constructor of a page called only once at the first time the page loaded. my page is very heavy, and every construction takes wasted time..

this my navigation code, usual one:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Pages/ContentControlNew.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

and this is the constructor of the page:

```
        public ContentControlNew()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Not special.. is it normal that the constructor is called every time? Please tell me if you need more details because I don't know what else to say about this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is normal because whenever you use NavigationService.Navigate it always creates a new page object and adds that (pushes it) to the navigation stack. For example when you use GoBack() it pops it out of the stack and destroys it, but when it gets back to the previous page it doesn't call the constructor since that one was already in the stack and does not have to be recreated.

If you don't want to create a page every time you navigate to it, you should look into Navigation Models for Windows Phone for some ideas on how you can tackle this.